# SQL Query alter table auto increment in SQL Plus Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have this SQL Query and I am trying to modify my column so it has an auto increment Property, But when I execute the query I either have a problem code ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

This is what I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE BF_USER DROP COLUMN USER_ID

ALTER TABLE BF_USER ADD USER_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Plus is Oracle's command-line tool. In that case:

```
SQL> create table bf_user (user_id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> alter table bf_user drop column user_id;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table bf_user add user_id number generated always as identity;

Table altered.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into bf_user(name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from bf_user;

NAME          USER_ID
---------- ----------
Littlefoot          1

SQL>
```

---

As you use Oracle 10g (which doesn't support identity columns), use combination of a sequence and a database trigger:

```
SQL> create table bf_user (user_id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence bf_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_bfu
  2    before insert on bf_user
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select bf_seq.nextval into :new.user_id from dual;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into bf_user (name) values ('Nayeon');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from bf_user;

   USER_ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Nayeon

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello! sorry for the late reply about the 3rd query, I encountered an error "invalid ALTER TABLE option" with an error code ORA-01735. Sorry I'm using an outdated version of SQL plus, and this is from my school laboratory and we are not allowed to update anything. This is the SQL*plus version Release 10.2.0.1.0. Is the error connected to the SQL*version? Because some of the solutions I've found are working perfectly for the others but not in my case. Thank you so much for your answers, I appreciated it. and I'm very sorry for the question.

Comment: IDENTITY COLUMN is available in 12c; as you're on 10g, that certainly won't work. If you have to implement such a feature in your version, you'd **a)** create a sequence, **b)** create a database trigger (BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW) which would use that sequence and put its value into the ID column.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented a sequence and that works. Thank you so much! by the way sorry again for additional questions. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all :)